# Make Ubuntu look like mac osX

Tags: macosx

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I have installed the latest version of Macbuntu, but it does not have the advanced mac os X efffects.
I want my desktop to have the effects like the one in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkN-gEUnICI

I am new to Ubuntu so please answer in full detail.

Your help will be appreciated.

P.S. : The uploader of the video says that he has used some hacks and I too am ready to do so.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at videos like that, always remember to check the date. Just a note.

That being said, what you are looking for (I believe you mean the "genie effect", is called "Magic Lamp", and is available in Compiz. First you must install `compizconfig-settings-manager`:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Then, run `ccsm`, go to "animations" and change your relevant animations to "Magic lamp".
[image: Obligatory Shot Of Screen]

Comment: i cannot edit ccsm. As soon as I tick the animations, it becomes unticked. I cannot view the options in the animations too.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to take a screenshot or record a video of this?